# gatsby build on hosting server > pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: gatsby

I want to build my gatsby app on my server.
Locally `gatsby build` is without problems, public dir is filled with the right files.
/public/ is in .gitignore, so on my server I want to `gatsby build` / `npm run build`

When I run `gatsby build` on my server, it stops with an error at:
 Building production JavaScript and CSS bundlesnode[2620173]: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
error UNHANDLED EXCEPTION

(shared hosting without root access, gatsby-cli is globally installed).
What could I do to be able to use the build script here?

Could it have something to do with this? :
gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 build /home/commun39/vdep-comm
gatsby build

lscpu: failed to determine number of CPUs: /sys/devices/system/cpu/possible: No such file or directory`

Thank you!